# Show that for sequence of independent random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ either converges or diverges almost surely

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove that for sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,...$, that are independent either the sum  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ converges almost surely or diverges almost surely.

Any tips on how to prove this result? Particularly I have a problem as the definition for almost sure divergence is not provided.

Comment: [Hewitt-Savage zero-one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law)

Comment: @angryavian Thanks!! :)

Comment: @angryavian You need “iid” condition to apply Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law. The OP is not assuming this.

Comment: @Rubertos Good point, thanks for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n(w)$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=k}^\infty X_n(w)$ is convergent, and vice versa.

Now, apply Kolmogorov 0-1 law.